# Is Brownian motion random or haphazard?

Tags: brownian-motion, random

According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness, randomness is a measure of uncertainty of an outcome, rather than haphazardness.

I was wondering if the Brownian motion is an example of haphazardness. If not, is there another example?

Comment: you're going to have to define 'haphazardness'. It is certainly random.

Comment: What is "haphazardness"? If you mean independent, Brownian Motion is not, because its value depends on the previous. If you mean correlated, it is, because of the last argument. If you mean random, well, it is clearly.